# C - What is the proper format to allow a function to show an error was encountered?

Tags: c, function, error-handling

I have a question about what a function should do if the arguments to said function don't line up quite right, through no fault of the function call. Since that sentence doesn't make much sense, I'll offer my current issue. To keep it simple, here is the most relevant and basic function I have.

```
float getYValueAt(float x, PHYS_Line line, unsigned short* error)

    *error = 0;    

    if(x < line.start.x || x > line.end.x){
        *error = 1;
        return -1;
    }

    if(line.slope.value != 0){
        //line's equation: y - line.start.y = line.slope.value(x - line.start.x)
        return line.slope.value * (x - line.start.x) + line.start.y;
    }

    else if(line.slope.denom == 0){
        if(line.start.x == x)
            return line.start.y;
        else{
            *error = 1;
            return -1;
        }
    }

    else if(line.slope.num == 0){
        return line.start.y;
    }
}
```

The function attempts to find the point on a line, given a certain x value. However, under some circumstances, this may not be possible. For example, on the line x = 3, if 5 is passed as a value, we would have a problem. Another problem arises if the chosen x value is not within the interval the line is on. For this, I included the error pointer. Given this format, a function call could work as follows:

```
void foo(PHYS_Line some_line){
    unsigned short error = 0;
    float y = getYValueAt(5, some_line, &error);
    if(error)
        fooey();
    else
        do_something_with_y(y);
}
```

My question pertains to the error. Note that the value returned is allowed to be negative. Returning -1 does not ensure that an error has occurred. I know that it is sometimes preferred to use the following method to track an error:

```
float* getYValueAt(float x, PHYS_Line line);
```

and then return NULL if an error occurs, but I believe this requires dynamic memory allocation, which seems even less sightly than the solution I was using. So, what is standard practice for an error occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not really a standard practice for this kind of error handling in C.

But a good handling in your specific case would be returning `NaN`, in other words `0.0/0.0`.

```
/* error else */
else {
    etc();
    return 0.0/0.0;
}
```

Which would yield NaN.  You can check if a value is not a number by comparing it with itself, as NaN is the only float/double value that will fail when comparing to itself.

```
yvalue = getYValueAt(...)
if (yvalue != yvalue) {
    treat_error_here();
}
```

This is just an option, there are other ways of handling this kinds of error.

Comment: Whoa, I never even knew that existed. Thank you very much. For a function that does not return a float, though, is there a way that works better than mine, and is my method acceptable?

Comment: Yes, it is acceptable.  What usually people do is to try to keep the error handling consistent through a whole library or system.  There is even other method: playing with the ``errno`` variable and the related definitions in [errno.h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errno.h) file.  It is on the standard C library, but since it is a simple error handling, it is not standard practice on various libraries.

Answer (score 3):

A common practice would be returning the error code and let the user pass a pointer to the result:

```
int getYValueAt(float x, PHYS_Line line, float *result)
```

the return value is usually 0 on success and an error code for failure. No dynamic allocation is required.